# Karate Robot - how to fetch element properties?

Tags: karate

I have been using the Karate framework for a while now and more recently its Robot component for desktop UI automation. I'm curious if there's a way to fetch the value of a given element property. Following this example from the documentation:

```
* def fun = function(){ return optional('Close').enabled }
* waitUntil(fun)
```

I'd like to be able to fetch the value of IsOffscreen, IsControlElement, etc.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question, so I've just [added a way to do it](https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/2240a2efa6361c281f8ff8131fc750c103285d8d), but unfortunately can't test it just yet: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-robot#property-value

```
* def button = locate('Close')
* def isOffScreen = button.property('IsOffscreen')
```

Would you be able to build this locally and test, that would really help. There is am easy developer guide; https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: Thanks, Peter! It works as expected, _almost_. The value returned is an integer, as opposed to a boolean. For example, this fails the assertion: `* match locateAll('Submit')[0].property(30034) == false match failed: EQUALS   $ | data types don't match (NUMBER:BOOLEAN)   0   false` But this works `* match locateAll('Submit')[0].property('IsOffscreen') == -1     * match locateAll('Submit')[0].property(30034) == 0`

Comment: @trebor great. and maybe this is all we can do because the method can potentially return *any* type, including string data. I think it will be too much to categorize the properties that can return booleans. converting an int to a boolean should be super-easy, so hope this suffices

Comment: Great point, Peter! That works. Thanks again for the quick turnaround!